# iPhone: Open new view controller after capturing video from camera

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to open new view controller just after pressing stop video capturing button.
I am using this code but i am unable to do this.

```
-(void)shootvideo
    {


    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;


        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;



        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];


    }




    -(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info 
    {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

         if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
         == kCFCompareEqualTo) 
         {

         NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

           NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


         if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
         UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
         }
         }


         [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

         // nextviewcontroller *test=[[nextviewcontroller alloc]init];

     //[self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];




         }

    }
```

Just after pressing the stop capturing video button I want to navigate to another view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible if you use performSelector with Delay time 0.2 near about ....here just call the method and its work fine
and in method you can push your nextViewController....
hope this help you...
:)

Answer (score 2):

You  have presented the image picker by `presentModalViewcontroller` so you cant call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];` on image picker. You have two options one is simple

1) Instead of calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` on image picker, just call

```
   nextviewcontroller *test=[[nextviewcontroller alloc]init];
   [self presentModalViewController:nextviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

2) Use delegates to call new view controller.